# Fourier Transform to Converting from DT to CT

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing

I am trying to convert the following discrete time signal to continuous time:

$$h[n]=
\begin{cases}
(-1)^n,  & 0\leq n \leq 3 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Using the transform pair:

$$a^n u[n] \leftrightarrow \frac{1}{1 +ae^{-j\Omega}}$$

gives:

$$H(\Omega) = \frac{1}{1 - e^{-j\Omega}}$$

However, this doesn't take into account the upper bound.

I think this problem may involve recognizing that $$(-1)^{n}==\cos[t\cdot\pi]$$

But I am not sure where to go from here.

The solution is

> $$H(\Omega) = \begin{cases}
>  \frac{1-e^{-j4\Omega}}{1+e^{-j\Omega}},  & \text{if $-e^{-j\Omega} \ne 1$} \\
>  4, & \text{if $\Omega = k\pi$, k odd}
>  \end{cases}$$
>
> Which can also be written as
>
> $$H(\Omega) = je^{-j3\Omega/2} \frac{\sin(2\Omega)}{\cos(\Omega/2)}$$

Thanks.